# Oracle SQL Procedure - Bad Bind Variable in REGEX

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have an Oracle SQL procedure which is giving `Bad bind variable 'VNAME1'` error on compilation. The idea is to pass the value of `item.tempid2` in the REGEX query.

The procedure below:

```
   DECLARE
    anyexists varchar2(10);
    CURSOR c_length IS SELECT SUBSTR(first_name,1,1)||substr(last_name) as 
    tempid2, user_id, Custom_Unique_Name FROM PV_USERS;
    vname1 varchar(20);
    exec vname1:= NULL;
    BEGIN
        FOR item in c_length
            LOOP
                EXIT WHEN c_length%notfound;
                vname1:= item.tempid2;
                SELECT COUNT(*) INTO anyexists from (SELECT 
                Custom_Unique_Name from PV_USERS
                WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (Custom_Unique_Name, '^'|| :vname1 || 
                '[^A-Za-z][0-9]*')
                AND user_id <> item.user_id);
             END LOOP;
     END;
```

Comment: the `vname` variable is already a bind variable, so there is no need for the `:` in front of it in the `regexp_like`.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a `USING vname1` clause at the end of your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: That would only be true if the select statement was dynamic sql being run via `execute immediate`. It's not, it's being run as a static statement.